# Delphi and InstallAware - Changing Root Folder when using Shortcut

Tags: ms-access, delphi, delphi-2010, installaware

I have a problem creating a shortcut using **InstallAware x9.**

**On Delphi:**

I use to link my database using Provider: Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider and Link it to my root folder as ./db/mdb.

here is my connection string := `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=db.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=puzzle33;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;`

On the other hand **(Installaware x9)**
I use to create a shortcut this was the parameter I setted:
Shortcut to File: MyExe

[image]

When I install the file it works fine, but when I run using the shortcut located at the desktop an error of my DATABASE (db.mdb) was not found on the location.
[image]

Is there something I missed? or Much better approach connecting DB and Delphi. Thanks.

Comment: in your connectionstring, the Data Source is db.mdb and not db/mdb

Comment: @ewong are you saying this is incorrect? Data Source=db.mdb?

Comment: yes, I see that but in your post, you mentioned ```I use to link my database using Provider: Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider and Link it to my root folder as ./db/mdb.```

Comment: Please disregard ./  this means only the root folder

Comment: isn't the Data Source supposed to be ```Data Source=db/mdb```?

Comment: @ewong I think not, MDB is a file extension which refers to access file

Comment: then shouldn't the Data Source refer to the full path of the db.mdb file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217853/discussion-between-justine-yeojson-barcelo-and-ewong).

Comment: Either use an absolute path to the .mdb or try setting the "Startup In Folder" parameter.